# bibliographystyle "te" not working with this LaTeX template

Tags: bibtex

I'm trying to use the `te` bibliography style [(available here)](https://www.economics.utoronto.ca/osborne/latex/TEBST.HTM) with [this LaTeX template](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis) and it just doesn't work.

I've placed the bst file under `<MikTeX folder>\local\bibtex\bst\te` and every folder under the template's directory structure.

Nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Did you run `texhash`? That updates the hash table containing the locations of whatever you have in your TeX Directory Structure. Also, are you running BibTeX after you did a regular compile? Please also explain what "it doesn't work" mean...

Comment: "Nothing seems to be working" is not very specific. What warning and/or error messages do you get? (Look for such messages in the .log and .blg files.) After storing `te.bst` in `<MikTeX folder>\local\bibtex\bst\te`, did you run the MikTeX utility that updates MikTeX's filename database (FNDB)? Have you tried placing the file `te.bst` in the directory where your main .tex file is located?

Comment: What I meant by "not working" is that, the citations are showing the default "[1]" rather than in the "Last Name (Year)" format that the te bibliography style should show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for providing the additional piece of information that you wish to use authoryear-style citation callouts.

The following instruction and comments are in the file `main.tex` that's provided by the package you're using:

```
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib} 
% Use the natbib reference package - read up on this to edit the reference style; 
% if you want text (e.g. Smith et al., 2012) for the in-text references (instead of 
% numbers), remove 'numbers'
```

Thus, just modify this instruction to either

```
\usepackage{natbib}
```

or

```
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
```

and you should be getting authoryear-style citation callouts. Be sure to run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to fully propagate all changes.